# thread does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I had a "void extends thread" for an object.

I made 2 buttons: A for thread object a and B thread for object b. The problem is the thread works well when i only press A or B but it doesn't work when i press B after A pressed. And I can't solve it. Please, show me how to fix it. Code likes this.

```
buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        thread(object a).run();
}
buttonB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        thread(object b).run();
}
```

Comment: 1) that's not real code, i.e. the object a and object b stuff won't compile, and 2) I'm not sure how we can guess what's wrong based on the limited information presented so far. I think that you'll need to both tell more and show more code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org) for us to begin to get close to understanding the problem. Without understanding there can be no solution. Who knows what a and b do? Lord only knows what "doesn't work" implies. We're smart and talented, but unfortunately not mind readers and can't begin to guess about code not shown.

Comment: based on his description, i would assume that his newly spawned thread is not actually being run as a thread and is blocking his UI thread. but yes, more context would be helpful.

Comment: Just as some extra info its not really good practice to extend Thread class unless adding functionality to it. [Rather implement a `Runnable`](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4202)

Answer (score 8):

Ah,  you're calling `run()` not `start()` on the Thread. This will not allow the thread to call its code on a background thread and instead will call it on the Swing event thread. Instead call `start()`. If that doesn't help, then please ask a better question.

Comment: +1 for `We're smart and talented`, in the comment.

Comment: +1 For being wrong on "not mind readers"

Comment: It was Alex Lynch who first saw this. I've up-voted several of his recent good answers for this.

Comment: i was just about to complain! as long as his question is answered :)

Comment: @AlexLynch: if you want to supply an answer, I'll gladly delete this one. Serious.

Comment: no need - reputation is but a number.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. AlexLynch. Have you both got `sportsmanship` badge yet? I guess certainly yes.

Comment: OK. I'll give more information.
I created a class EsausWilliams extends Thread.
Follow is my main class:
'buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        EsausWilliams es = new EsausWilliams(condition a);
        es.excutes();     (excute() means run())
}
buttonB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
        EsausWilliams es = new EsausWilliams(condition b);
        es.excutes();     (excute() means run())
}'
The problem is as I said.
No more characters left for me to explain more.

Comment: @warriork34: you can't post code in a comment since it is unreadable (as you can see). Also the question has been closed and will likely be deleted. I suggest that you create a new question, and provide even more information and code, enough so that we'll be able to understand your problem and have a prayer at being able to answer it.